# Create new master detail page not working in Xamarin, naming classes wrong?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to do something quite simple that worked fine before but has stopped working. Creating a new MasterDetailPage.

In a fresh new project when creating a new MasterDetailPage, it's leaving errors about "The type or namespace "x" could not be found".

What's happening is it's naming the new classes wrong by doubling up the last section. For example "MasterDetailPageMainMenuItemMenuItem" instead of "MasterDetailPageMainMenuItem", and "MasterDetailPageMainMasterMaster" instead of "MasterDetailPageMainMaster". Same with the Detail page.

What on earth is causing this?

Comment: What is the version of your IDE? It's seems an existing issue of VS for windows .And It works fine on vs for mac . I will add a new bug thread on github and we will focus on it .

Comment: Visual Studio 2019, with all the latest Xamarin packages and such.

Comment: I have post your issue in github .And we will focus on it .